# Polymer 1.0: User authentication UX (recommendations, tutorials and examples)?

Tags: authentication, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

Is there a recommended "Polymer way" to do user authentication?

This question includes both the technical pieces AND the UX.

A soup-to-nuts example (and/or tutorial) of a UX for doing user auth would be fantastic.

*Note: The Polymer Starter Kit does not contain any authentication UX examples.*

In this question...

**"UX" means:**

The COMPLETE "user-experience" involved in signing up for a new account, logging in and handling forgotten user id or password. For example, a typical landing page for a typical web app will usually have some buttons in the upper right corner for signing up for a new account and logging in. What happens when someone clicks those buttons and how to handle the entire flow would be a very useful example for Polymer developers given that functionality is necessary for most modern web apps. I would love to not have to create my own amateurish "home-brew" concoction from scratch for a solution but, instead, to have something relatively professional and generic I can "plug-n-play" into my app and modify only if/when necessary.

Comment: your question is not clear explain it what you want?

Comment: you can use iron-form or iron-ajax to authenticate user by requesting from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a custom element with all the relevant styles, templates and scripts to express the UX.